# Setting Up SYS_REFCURSOR in PL\SQL to return dataset

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sys-refcursor

I have a PL\SQL that returns a data set that essentially verifies volumes by account||product in two different tables.

My end goal is to have this data set pull directly into a spreadsheet (using Excel-VBA) by passing date parameters (provided through Excel) and calling the stored-procedure.

After reading a bit on PL\SQL it appears that I need a cursor variable to store the end result data set that is provided so I can then write it to the spreadsheet (as a recordset).

Following examples online, I've written my procedure like so

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_REG_SPLIT_RECON (dStart IN Date, dEnd IN Date) 
-- procedure to check regional splits creation is okay
-- procedure checks volumes by account and product from FACT_TRADE_PRESPLIT_ROLLUP to FACT_TRADE_ROLLUP

-- SQLDeveloper doesn't like this section and I can't figure out how to set this up correctly, no matter what I do and research.

RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR 
AS 
l_return SYS_REFCURSOR; 
-- end of section not working

BEGIN

OPEN l_return FOR 

    SELECT OpStats.Account, OpStats.Platform, OpStats.Volume OpStatsVol, RegSplits.Volume RegSplitsVol, (OpStats.Volume-RegSplits.Volume) Difference FROM

   (a bunch of union queries) OpStats,

   (a bunch of other union queries) RegSplits

WHERE OpStats.Account = RegSplits.Account (+) And OpStats.Platform = RegSplits.Platform (+)
ORDER BY OpStats.Account ASC, OPStats.Platform DESC;

RETURN l_return;

END;
```

FWIW, the queries work fine and return results as expected. Does anyone know why my PL\SQL is not compiling? Or if I am way off base in my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating Function as RETURN statement is only  used in FUCNTION. RETURN statement in PROCEDURE is only used for TERMINATING the procedure normally at desired position. Hope below code helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PROC_REG_SPLIT_RECON( --Function has to be incorporated
    dStart IN DATE,
    dEnd   IN DATE)
  -- procedure to check regional splits creation is okay
  -- procedure checks volumes by account and product from FACT_TRADE_PRESPLIT_ROLLUP to FACT_TRADE_ROLLUP
  -- SQLDeveloper doesn't like this section and I can't figure out how to set this up correctly, no matter what I do and research.
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  l_return SYS_REFCURSOR;
  -- end of section not working
BEGIN
  OPEN l_return FOR SELECT OpStats.Account, OpStats.Platform, OpStats.Volume OpStatsVol, RegSplits.Volume RegSplitsVol, (OpStats.Volume-RegSplits.Volume) Difference FROM (a bunch OF
  UNION queries) OpStats, (a bunch OF other
  UNION queries) RegSplits WHERE OpStats.Account = RegSplits.Account (+) AND OpStats.Platform = RegSplits.Platform (+) ORDER BY OpStats.Account ASC, OPStats.Platform DESC;
  RETURN l_return;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a Oracle procedure and a procedure cannot have a RETURN keyword with a specified return datatype. Create a Oracle function to do what you want to do.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUN_REG_SPLIT_RECON 
...
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
....
```